# Reverse Iteration of an STL Algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, reverse-iterator

I have a function that is being called with 2 pointers for arguments, the beginning and and ending of an array. My function will search from the end pointer to the beginning pointer for an element that matches a condition.

If I was trying to iterate forward I could do this with `find_if` but I need to iterate in reverse. Does the STL have any provision for this?

Note: I can easily do this in a for loop. What I'm looking for is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Sadly no, the I am simply providing a function to be called by some nasty code that I'm working with.

Comment: I missed the point indicating it was plain array, and there is already a solution so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is called [std::reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator). An example:

```
template<typename RandomAccessIterator>
void reverse_sort(RandomAccessIterator begin, RandomAccessIterator end) {
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<RandomAccessIterator> r_iter_t;
    std::sort(r_iter_t(end), r_iter_t(begin));
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    reverse_sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    for(auto i : arr) std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

gives

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: `std::begin` and `std::end` do not work on function parameters. They only work on locally declared fixed size array pointers.

Comment: @JonathanMee `begin`/`end` work on quite a few things, including arrays that are passed to your function by reference, but that is besides the point. You have a begin and end iterator, just pass them where I pass my begin and end iterators. *How* you get them does not actually matter.

Comment: @JonathanMee I have rewritten the example so you can see why `std::begin`/`std::end` do not have any impact on the viability of the solution

Comment: You can use `std::make_reverse_iterator` to do the type deduction automatically.

Comment: @C.R. Finally. I was not aware that this had been added to C++1y.

Comment: @C.R. I'm limited to C++11, so I don't have access to `std::make_reverse_iterator`

Comment: @C.R. A quick check shows that this is not supported by any of my compilers yet (VS2013, g++ 4.9, clang 3.4 or icc/win 14.0)

Comment: @gha.st So I tried your solution locally using, `reverse_sort( arr, arr + 3 );` To my shock that works, how can that be? I thought we weren't allowed to construct iterators from pointers?

Comment: @JonathanMee Pointers fulfill every requirement for a RandomIterator, meaning that pointers *are* iterators. In fact, e.g. `vector::begin` usually just returns a pointer.

Comment: @gha.st: vector::begin returns a pointer only in very old version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Why do you think constructing iterators from pointers are not allowed?

Comment: So that is to say my function wouldn't need templating or typecasting: `int foo( int* rend, int* rbegin ){ return &*find_if( std::reverse_iterator< int* >( rbegin ), std::reverse_iterator< int* >( rend ), myCondition ); }`